# How to get dynamic status of file upload in angular ui from java rest service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, progress-bar, angular-file-upload

As part of my requirement need to show dynamic progress bar about uploaded file to user. I am using Java rest service for placing file into a separate location. Is there any way to get upload% from rest service and pass it to UI angular application

Comment: It really depends on the REST service and what library/framework you're using for the AJAX call.

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034375/angular-file-upload-progress-percentage

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042623/upload-angularjs-file-with-progress-percentage

Comment: Hi Ivan Rubinson, Thanks for response. but I am using Angular 1.5 version and Java rest services as Back end, Any references for the same would help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use angular2 http API for tracking upload/download progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42231123/how-to-use-angular2-http-api-for-tracking-upload-download-progress)